# Как превратить заголовок статьи в изображение?

Tags: скрипт, соцсети, сниппет

Здравствуйте! Возможно, кто-то знает, как сделать так, чтобы заголовок статьи/новости оказывался на картинке при репосте в соцсети? Или направьте, пожалуйста, где можно узнать об этом больше) 
[image: Пример того, как это выглядит. Каким-то образом это делается автоматически]

Спасибо за любую помощь и совет)

Answer (score 1):

- Установите ваш заголовок в **[мета тайтл](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp)** - смотрите также **[Как обеспечить показ информативных заголовков и описаний страниц в результатах поиска Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=ru)** ++ **[Title Tag of Moz](https://moz.com/learn/seo/title-tag)**.
- Установите ваш заголовок как значение для **[элемента H1](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp)** конкретной веб-страницы. Смотрите также **[HTML/Usage/Headings/h1only of W3](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Usage/Headings/h1only)**. Не требуется точного соответствия со значением мета тайтла, но общая тема/смысл важна.
- Примените **[структурированные данные](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data)** отображающие главную тему содержания веб-страницы, например с типом **[NewsArticle](http://schema.org/NewsArticle)** и примените свойство name для вашего значения элемента H1. Например:

```html
<article vocab=http://schema.org/ typeof=NewsArticle>
<h1 property=name>Военного атташе США...</h1>
</article>
```

Все эти разметки помогут поисковой оптимизации. Многие социальны сети также используют эту разметку, например **[Pinterest](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/)**, **Google Plus** и другие.

Для Facebooka требуется создание особых мета тэгов как **[Разметка Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters)**. Например для статьи:

```html
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="302184056577324" /> 
  <meta property="og:type" content="article" /> 
  <meta property="og:url" content="урл вашей статьи" /> 
  <meta property="og:title" content="Военного атташе США..." /> 
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://example.ru/images/image.png" />
```

Смотрите также **[документацию Facebook о статьях](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/article/)**. Эти мета тэги Гугл также применяет, хотя и не показывает это в своём **[валидаторе структурированных данных](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)** (на страом валидаторе это было показано).

Для Twitter также требуется отдельные мета тэги как **[Twitter Cards](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/getting-started)**.

Обратите внимание, что все вышеуказанные мета тэги используют свойство **name**. В значение этого свойства вы можете устанавливать ваши заголовки.

Comment: Спасибо. Это уже настроено. Но вот каким образом заголовок становится картиной новости при репосте в соцсети, как на примере? Вот это интересно)

Comment: Я думаю, что это закрытая внутренняя информация соц.сетей. Я не знаю информацию об этом и не мог найти это.

Comment: В любом случае спасибо. Буду искать дальше, как СМИ это настраивают :)